# How to remove redundant Spring MVC method by providing POST-only @Valid?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have a form-handling Spring MVC controller with JSR-303 bean validation by `@Valid`.

The only purpose of whole `GET`-handler is to act (almost) the same as `POST`, but omitting `@Valid` annotation to prevent displaying of errors in JSP `<form:errors ...>`on the first user `GET` request before he submits the form.

My question is:

- How can I remove the redundant `GET` method in a clean way?
- How can I make a `POST`-only `@Valid`?

Here is my example code:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/account/register" , method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String registerGet( @ModelAttribute( "registerForm" ) RegisterForm registerForm ) {
    return "account/register";
}

@RequestMapping( value = "/account/register" , method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String registerPost( @ModelAttribute( "registerForm" ) @Valid RegisterForm registerForm ,
        BindingResult result ,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes ) {

    ... ADD USER HERE IF !result.hasErrors() ...

    return "account/register";
}
```

Comment: No way to have to configure @Valid only if method is post without making so many modifcation that it will be a spaghetti code. You can keep the two methods, with a private methods that do the job for both.

Comment: @farvilain but you must admit, that my code is definatelly no "Don't repeat yourself" compilant. There should be a better way.

Comment: And what if you add something like : if(!result.hasErrors || request.getMethod().equals("get") ) ?

Comment: @farvilain The problem is not about code in handling method, the problem is with JSP `<form:errors...>` tag from spring taglib, which always displays errors (even on first - GET - request)

Comment: @farvilain It is possible without spaghetti code or repeating yourself. You only need to dive into Spring MVC a bit more and understand how argument resolvers and request binding works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look how spring resolves the arguments passed to the handler it is not very difficult to implement your own that does exactly what you want. By default spring will use the [`ModelAttributeMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html) for arguments annotated with `@ModelAttribute` and simple types.

*Just look at the `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.supportsParameter()` method implementation.*

```
/**
 * @return true if the parameter is annotated with {@link ModelAttribute}
 * or in default resolution mode also if it is not a simple type.
 */
@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    if (parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(ModelAttribute.class)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (this.annotationNotRequired) {
        return !BeanUtils.isSimpleProperty(parameter.getParameterType());
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` is also responsible for kicking in the validation if the `@Valid` annotation is found. It does this in a interesting way to make the code compile without `@Valid` being on the classpath. Luckily this makes it easy to exploit in your advantage.

*The extracted `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable() method.`*

```
/**
 * Validate the model attribute if applicable.
 * <p>The default implementation checks for {@code @javax.validation.Valid}.
 * @param binder the DataBinder to be used
 * @param parameter the method parameter
 */
protected void validateIfApplicable(WebDataBinder binder, MethodParameter parameter) {
    Annotation[] annotations = parameter.getParameterAnnotations();
    for (Annotation annot : annotations) {
        if (annot.annotationType().getSimpleName().startsWith("Valid")) {
            Object hints = AnnotationUtils.getValue(annot);
            binder.validate(hints instanceof Object[] ? (Object[]) hints : new Object[] {hints});
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

As you may already noticed it simply checks if there is a annotation present on the parameter that starts with `"Valid"` and tells the binder to validate it's value.

### Write a custom annotation

The first thing to do is to write a new annotation which your custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` will support.

```
//** Validates only when the request method is a modifying verb e.g. POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE */
@Target({ PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidModifyingVerb {}
```

**Notice the name of the annotation intentionally starts with `"Valid"`.**

### Rolling out your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

The easiest thing to do is to extend `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` and modify it's behavior. Since the `resolveArgument()` method is **final** you cannot override it. What we can do is override the following three methods:

1. `supportsParameter(final MethodParameter parameter)`:

> Tells spring this resolver support arguments annotated with `@ValidModifyingVerb`.

`bindRequestParameters(final WebDataBinder binder, final NativeWebRequest request)`:

> Will be the perfect candidate to obtain a reference to the request and looking up it's request method. It also gives you the chance to omit binding the parameter when we don't need it to be.

`validateIfApplicable(final WebDataBinder binder, final MethodParameter parameter)`:

> Gives you the opportunity to omit validation. If you need validation it will be automatically picked up since your own annotation starts with `"Valid"` is well.

Implementing the above will result in a class similar to this.

```
public class ValidModifyingVerbMethodArgumentResolver extends ModelAttributeMethodProcessor {

    private String requestMethod;

    /**
     * @param annotationNotRequired if "true", non-simple method arguments and
     *                              return values are considered model attributes with or without a
     *                              {@code @ModelAttribute} annotation.
     */
    public ValidModifyingVerbMethodArgumentResolver(final boolean annotationNotRequired) {
        super(annotationNotRequired);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(final MethodParameter parameter) {
        return super.supportsParameter(parameter) && parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(ValidModifyingVerb.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindRequestParameters(final WebDataBinder binder, final NativeWebRequest request) {
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = request.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        requestMethod = servletRequest.getMethod();
        if (isModifyingMethod(requestMethod)) {
            ((ServletRequestDataBinder) binder).bind(servletRequest);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void validateIfApplicable(final WebDataBinder binder, final MethodParameter parameter) {
        if (isModifyingMethod(requestMethod)) {
            super.validateIfApplicable(binder, parameter);
        }
    }

    private boolean isModifyingMethod(String method) {
        return !"GET".equals(method);
    }
}
```

The only thing left is to register `ValidModifyingVerbMethodArgumentResolver` as a argument resolver in your application context configuration and you're done.

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new ValidModifyingVerbMethodArgumentResolver(true));
    }
}
```

The handler methods in your controller can now be reduced to:

```
@RequestMapping("/account/register")
public String registerPost(
        @ValidModifyingVerb RegisterForm registerForm,
        BindingResult result,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    //... ADD USER HERE IF !result.hasErrors() ...

    return "account/register";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not remove the GET method at all as you want to use it to rendering jsp page for first time, what I'm doing is just adding only `Model model` as method parameter, and use `model.add("form", new MyForm());`, so there is no mapping in GET method. so your get method can be:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/account/register" , method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String registerGet( Model model ) {
model.add("registerForm",new RegisterForm());
    return "account/register";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a good way to remove the get method, since you need the Controller to do a specific action (instantiate the form bean and add it to the model) on a GET.

However, you *can* reduce the duplication quite a bit.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account/register")  //move path to class level for all @RequestMapping methods to inherit
public class MyController {

    //just add the form object to the model on GET; infer the view name from the url
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ModelAttribute //let Spring pick a good name for it
    public RegisterForm registerGet() {
        return new RegisterForm();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void registerPost(
            @ModelAttribute @Valid RegisterForm registerForm,
            BindingResult result ,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes ) {

        ... ADD USER HERE IF !result.hasErrors() ...

        // don't return anything and let spring infer the view name from the url
    }

}
```

Relevant bits from the Spring 3.2 documentation:

> The @ModelAttribute annotation can be used on @RequestMapping methods as well. In that case the return value of the @RequestMapping method is interpreted as a model attribute rather than as a view name. The view name is derived from view name conventions instead much like for methods returning void — see Section 17.12.3, “The View - RequestToViewNameTranslator”.

...

> The DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator is tasked with generating a logical view name from the URL of the request. In the case of the above RegistrationController, which is used in conjunction with the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping, a request URL of `http://localhost/registration.html` results in a logical view name of registration being generated

Comment: Just be be careful not to declare a argument of type `ServletResponse` or `ServletResponse` which will indicate you're handling the response yourself in case of a `void` return type.