# Spring Boot JPA - paging and sorting

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to implement pagination to my Spring Data JPA repository in Spring Boot but I am stuck with the following exception when running uni tests:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
...
```

Could someone point out to me what am I missing here? This is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface VenueRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Venue, Long> {

    public Page<Venue> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

and controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/venues")
public class VenueController {

    @Autowired
    private VenueRepository venueRepo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Venue>> getVenues(Pageable pageable) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(venueRepo.findAll(pageable), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and finally my test:

```
@Test
public void responseOkVenuesTest() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(get("/venues").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

I spent couple of hours trying to make this work and am running out of ideas. Thank you for any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method `getVenues` in the way that you can pass the parameters to instantiate a `PageRequest` instead of passing `Pageable` :

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<List<Venue>> getVenues(int from,int to) {
     return new ResponseEntity<>(
        venueRepo.findAll((new PageRequest(from, to)), HttpStatus.OK).getContent();
  }
```

Comment: This produces null pointer exception if this parameter is not present (I would like it to be optional). I hoped there was some 'spring' way to this

Comment: @Smajl not sure if it works, but does `@RequestParam(value = "from", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int from` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @[SEY_91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4687221/sey-91)'s answer you might also like to use the following solution inspired with [How to remove redundant Spring MVC method by providing POST-only @Valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310127/how-to-remove-redundant-spring-mvc-method-by-providing-post-only-valid) and used in my Spring Boot-driven application for long time.

In short, here is an annotation to annotate controller method parameters:

```java
@Target(PARAMETER)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface PlainModelAttribute {
}
```

Now, just a method processor that would scan for parameters annotated with `@PlainModelAttribute`:

```java
public final class PlainModelAttributeMethodProcessor
        extends ModelAttributeMethodProcessor {

    private final Map<TypeToken<?>, Converter<? super NativeWebRequest, ?>> index;

    private PlainModelAttributeMethodProcessor(final Map<TypeToken<?>, Converter<? super NativeWebRequest, ?>> index) {
        super(true);
        this.index = index;
    }

    public static HandlerMethodArgumentResolver plainModelAttributeMethodProcessor(final Map<TypeToken<?>, Converter<? super NativeWebRequest, ?>> index) {
        return new PlainModelAttributeMethodProcessor(index);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(final MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(PlainModelAttribute.class) || super.supportsParameter(parameter);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createAttribute(final String attributeName, final MethodParameter parameter, final WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory,
            final NativeWebRequest request) {
        final TypeToken<?> typeToken = TypeToken.of(parameter.getGenericParameterType());
        final Converter<? super NativeWebRequest, ?> converter = index.get(typeToken);
        if ( converter == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find a converter for " + typeToken.getType());
        }
        return converter.convert(request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindRequestParameters(final WebDataBinder binder, final NativeWebRequest request) {
        final HttpServletRequest servletRequest = request.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        if ( !isSafe(resolve(servletRequest.getMethod())) ) {
            ((ServletRequestDataBinder) binder).bind(servletRequest);
        }
    }

    private static HttpMethod resolve(final String name) {
        return HttpMethod.valueOf(name.toUpperCase());
    }

    private static boolean isSafe(final HttpMethod method)
            throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        switch ( method ) {
        case GET:
        case HEAD:
        case OPTIONS:
            return true;
        case POST:
        case PUT:
        case PATCH:
        case DELETE:
            return false;
        case TRACE:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        default:
            throw new AssertionError(method);
        }
    }

}
```

I don't really remember, but a `resolve()` method equivalent should be present in Spring Framework somewhere. Note that I use Google Guava [TypeToken](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) in order to let the processor be compatible with generic types (since I use models like `IQuery<Foo>` and `IQuery<Bar>` in controllers). Now just register the processor:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration
        extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(createModelAttributeMethodProcessor());
    }

    private static HandlerMethodArgumentResolver createModelAttributeMethodProcessor() {
        return plainModelAttributeMethodProcessor(ImmutableMap.of(pageableTypeToken, MvcConfiguration::toPageable));
    }

    private static final TypeToken<Pageable> pageableTypeToken = new TypeToken<Pageable>() {
    };

    private static Pageable toPageable(final WebRequest request) {
        return new PageRequest(
                ofNullable(request.getParameter("page")).map(Integer::parseInt).orElse(0),
                ofNullable(request.getParameter("size")).map(Integer::parseInt).orElse(1)
        );
    }

}
```

Here is a web request to a `Pageable` DTO conversion, and the converter must be registered as an argument resolver. So now it's ready to use:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public String get(@PlainModelAttribute final Pageable pageable) {
        return toStringHelper(pageable)
                .add("offset", pageable.getOffset())
                .add("pageNumber", pageable.getPageNumber())
                .add("pageSize", pageable.getPageSize())
                .add("sort", pageable.getSort())
                .toString();
    }

}
```

A few examples:

- `/` ⇒ `PageRequest{offset=0, pageNumber=0, pageSize=1, sort=null}`
- `/?page=43` ⇒ `PageRequest{offset=43, pageNumber=43, pageSize=1, sort=null}`
- `/?size=32` ⇒ `PageRequest{offset=0, pageNumber=0, pageSize=32, sort=null}`
- `/?page=22&size=32` ⇒ `PageRequest{offset=704, pageNumber=22, pageSize=32, sort=null}`